Docker Resolving both host DNS and container names
The situation
I have a host on which I run a bunch of containers so I just Nginx Proxy manager to proxy HTTP traffic to their respective containers. However, I'd like it to be able to access devices on my Tailscale network and the only proper way I've seen it be able to be do is by giving the container access to the hosts network stack.
There is the option to let a container use the tailscale network stack However I've noticed that this is unreliable, and that this allows for accessing a container from a remote, but not a remote from a container. I believe it's supposed to work for both ways, but I was never able to get that working.
The problem
However, when I use the network_mode: host option it appears that that container can now no longer resolve docker container names. So that would mean that I can either resolve container names on my proxymesh network, or my tailscale devices when I'd like to use both.
The question
Is there a way to both use the hosts network stack, and resolve docker container names?
What I tried before
I tried using the tailscale way of connecting the container to my network.
This did not work properly and only allowed traffic to go one way.
and I don't like this as I'd like to have as few hosts on my tailscale network as possible
adding the container to both the proxymesh, and host network
but this caused an issues like:
Error response from daemon: invalid endpoint settings:
network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks

Looking online
I was able to find a similar question however it remains unanswered to this day.
My compose file:
services:
  proxy:
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    hostname: reverse-proxy
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host
    # networks: # cannot be used with `network_mode: host`
    #   - host
    #   - proxymesh
    dns: 
      - 127.0.0.11      # dockers DNS server, I as far as I thought?
      - 100.100.100.100 # tailscale DNS server ip
      - 1.1.1.1         # cloudflares DNS server
    ports: # ports are ignored when using `network_mode: host`
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 81:81
    extra_hosts: # this was in the template, but if I'm being honest I don't fully get what it does.
    - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/data:/data
      - ${PWD}/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
networks:
  proxymesh:
    external: true


network_mode: host completely disables the Docker networking layer.  You should almost never need this option, though; for things that aren't short names Docker will normally proxy DNS requests out to the host system's DNS resolver.

So it turns out that docker cannot resolve tailscale DNS names because of tailscale themselves. As you can see by this tailscale post. The solution to give docker containers access to your tailnet is by running:
tailscale up --stateful-filtering=false # did you read the warning?


WARNING: running the command will make it theoretically possible for machines on your LAN to forward packets and sent data over your tailnet to a host. Use with caution. Read the post for more information.

